# Renaming folders and files with a GUI

Tags: python, user-interface

Python community,

today  I tried to write a GUI script to be able to rename folders or files depending on what the user wants to do. I created two different Buttons: One for the Renaming of Folders, One for the Renaming of Files.
My Problem is that if I have f.e. a folder with several folders and several .txt files in it, my script is not able to just rename the folders or just rename the .txt files.

To solve this problem I had the idea to use the os.path.isdir function to generate a list of TRUE and FALSE values, with the folders refering as TRUE and then rename the objects which fullfill this condition.
Because I am relatively new to programming my knowledge is limited and therfore I would be very glad if somebody would be so kind to give me an idea how to improve my code and be able to design my GUI as I wish to.

Here is a part of my code (just a bit from my bigger GUI code):

```
import os

Pattern = self.PatternName.text()

#Rename Folders
objects = os.listdir(self.folders)
i = 0
for folder in objects:
    os.rename(os.path.join(self.folders, folder),
              os.path.join(self.folders, Pattern + str(i)))
    i += 1

#Rename Files
files = os.listdir(self.files)
i = 0
for file in files:
    filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file)
    os.rename(os.path.join(self.files, file), 
              os.path.join(self.files, Pattern + str(i) + file_extension))
    i += 1
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Best regards,
Kim

Answer (score 0):

Try using python's os.walk function. From [python 2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk):(also available in [python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk))

> For each directory in the tree rooted at directory top (including top
>   itself), it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames, filenames)

I don't know if this is exactly what you want to do, as this recursively walks down the whole directory structure, and not just the next-level of directories.